# Get a token from a rest api with vbnet. Method POST

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get a token from a ws but so far I have not succeeded.
From postman if I get the token but from my vbnet application no.
The code I use in vbnet is:

```
Dim client = New RestClient("https://xxxxxxxx.com/IntegrationAPI_2/api/login")
Dim request2 = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
request2.AddParameter("application/json", ParameterType.RequestBody)
request2.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
request2.AddParameter("Username", UserVar)
request2.AddParameter("Password", PasswVar)
Dim response2 As RestResponse = client.Execute(request2)
```

The result obtained in vbnet in statuscode is 0, but in postman it is 200 ok

I am programming in visual studio 2015. Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is an english-only site. Please make sure your post is in english only.

Comment: I removed the non-English version of your question. Please review and make sure that all relevant information is there. I think some prose explanation in English would help. Compare [ask]. And please consider taking the [tour], it might clarify some misunderstandings for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls

URLSERVICE += "?username=" & User & "&password=" & Passw

Dim client = New RestClient("" & URLSERVICE & "")
Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")

request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
Dim response As RestResponse = client.Execute(request)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).